# Parsing HTML content with sibling tags in Java (or) Finding content between two <open> tags

Tags: java, html, parsing, nested, htmlcleaner

Background: I'm writing a Java program to go through HTML files and replace all the content in tags that are not `<script>` or `<style>` with Lorem Ipsum. I originally did this with a regex just removing everything between a > and a <, which actually worked quite well (blasphemous I know), but I'm trying to turn this into a tool others may find useful so I wouldn't dare threaten the sanctity of the universe any more by trying to use regex on html.

I'm trying to use HtmlCleaner, a Java library that attracted me because it has no other dependencies. However, trying to implement it I've been unable to deal with html like this:

```
<div>
    This text is in the div <span>but this is also in a span.</span>
</div>
```

The problem is simple. When the TagNodeVisitor reaches the div, if I replace its contents with the right amount of lipsum, it will eliminate the span tag. But if I drill down to only TagNodes with no other children, I would miss the first bit of text.

HtmlCleaner has a ContentNode object, but that object has no replace method. Anything I can think of to deal with this seems like it must be far too complicated. Is anyone familiar with a way to deal with this, with HtmlCleaner or some other parsing library you're more familiar with?

Comment: Have you looked using something like a StringTokenizer? Just thinking out loud here.

Comment: I believe that's just a simplified regex and is now deprecated - from the Java docs "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead." Regex was actually working decently for me but using regex on html is apparently a terrible thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty much do anything you want with [JSoup setters](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/modifying-data/set-html)

Would that suit you ?

```
 Element div = doc.select("div").first(); // <div></div>
 div.html("<p>lorem ipsum</p>"); // <div><p>lorem ipsum</p></div>
```

Comment: I don't think so. I poked around the jSoup documentation, but I couldn't find anything that could replace the text between an open tag and the open tag of a child element. (trying to apply your example code to my example html wouldn't preserve the interior span).

Comment: what would be the result of the transformation made by your tool then in the case there is text after the span but inside the div ?

Comment: I want it to take `<div>text here <span>more text</span> and here</div>` and spit out `<div>lorem ipsum <span>dolor sit</span> amet nuncam</div>`. I want to replace any text between two tags whether they are both open, both close, or open and close.

Comment: Well you could get the deepest nodes first, and then go up and apply the transformations you want. 

So in this case, when a node has no children you can replace it's full html content, if the current nodes has children, then you can use, append(), prepend() or wrap().

It can rapidly gets messy, so I guess I am actually missing the big picture.

Answer (score 0):

HtmlCleaner's ContentNode has a method [getContent()](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/doc/org/htmlcleaner/ContentNode.html#getContent%28%29) that returns a [java.lang.StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). This is mutable and can be changed to whatever value you want.